# SSH remote login without password is very slow

Tags: macos, debian, openssh

SSH Client - Mac OS X Lion
SSH Server - Debian

/etc/hosts on Mac -> [IP of Debian] mydebian
Public key of Mac has already been put to authorized_key in root@mydebian:/root/.ssh
'UseDNS no' has been put to root@mydebian:/etc/ssh/sshd_config and then SSH server restarted

ssh root@mydebian -> wait for a long time to login
ssh -v root@mydebian -> no delay at all

Any ideas?

Comment: Any interesting output with `-v` / `-vvv`?

Comment: Can you format this better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the following value in `/etc/ssh_config`:

```
AddressFamily inet
```

(You can set it in `~/.ssh/config` as well.)

The reason is that ssh is trying to do IPv6 negotiation, which apparently fails after a timeout, which happened to me after migration to a new Lion (10.7.4) MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the negative? Put the IP of the source machine in the /etc/hosts and check what happens.